# Node.js server with client slide javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I currently have a node.js server which is connected to an HTML page. In that HTML page, I have javascript which is used to create a chart from a csv file. My problem is that when the server is running, I am unable to access the csv file from the javascript. The error is : Cannot GET /Users/danzam284/Desktop/DailyTracker-main/data.csv. The csv file is located in the same directory as everything else.

However when I run the HTML page alone without the server, the data is able to be collected from the csv file and no errors occur.

Here is the HTML file with the javascript:

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'data.csv',
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(content) {
                    const CSVToArray = (data) =>
                        data
                        .slice(data.indexOf('\n') + 1)
                        .split('\n')
                        .map(v => v.split(','))

                    content = CSVToArray(content);
                    content.pop();

                    let day = [];
                    let water = [];
                    let hard = [];

                    for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                        day.push(content[i][0]);
                        water.push(content[i][1]);
                        hard.push(content[i][2]);
                    }
                    const data = {
                    labels: day,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Number of Glasses per Day',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(51,153,255)',
                            borderColor: 'rgb(51,153,255)',
                            data: water
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Number of Hours spent on Frog',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,102,17)',
                            borderColor: 'rgb(0,102,17)',
                            data: hard
                        }
                        ]
                    };

                    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx , {
                        type: "line",
                        data: data, 
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Please let me know why this error only occurs. If you need any more info, feel free to ask.

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { response } = require('express');
const app = express();


var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var mostRecentName = null;


//Keeps login form address
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});

//Runs when login form is completed
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(301, {"Location": __dirname + "/index.html"});

    let name = req.body.name;
    mostRecentName = name;
    let email = req.body.email;

    let row = '*' + name + ', ' + email + '\n';

    //reinserts all of the previously removed data to the file

    fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/mem.txt', row, function(e) {
        if (e) {
            return console.log(e);
        }
    })
    return res.end(); 
});

//keeps water/hard form address
app.get(__dirname + '/index.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//Runs when water/hard form is submitted
app.post('/index.html', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(301, {"Location": __dirname + "/complete.html"});
    fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/mem.txt',req.body.day + ', ' + req.body.water + ', ' +  req.body.hard + '\n', function(e) {
        if (e) {
            return console.log(e);
        }
    })
    res.end();
});

//keeps complete address
app.get(__dirname + '/complete.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/complete.html');
});

//keeps results address
app.get(__dirname + '/results.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/results.html');
});

//runs when complete form is done
app.post('/complete.html', urlencodedParser = async function(req, res) {
    await parseData();
    res.writeHead(301, {"Location": __dirname + "/results.html"});
    res.end();
});


//converts txt data into a csv file based on last user
async function parseData() {
    csv = await findCommon();

    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/data.csv', csv, function(e) {
        if (e) {
            return console.log(e);
        }
    });
}


async function findCommon() {
    var csv = "date, water, hard\n";
    var data = await fs.readFile(__dirname + "/mem.txt", 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        return data;
    });


    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] === '*' && i + mostRecentName.length < data.length) {
            let curr = "";
            if (data.slice(i + 1, i + mostRecentName.length + 1) == mostRecentName) {
                while (data[i] != '\n') {
                    i++;
                }
                if (i < data.length - 1) {
                    i += 1
                }
                while (data[i] != '\n') {
                    curr += data[i];
                    i += 1;
                }
                curr += data[i];
            }
            csv += curr;
        }
    }
    return csv;
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000); //keeps running on port 3000
```

Comment: Why do you think that the server-side code you haven't shown us should support the path `/Users/danzam284/Desktop/DailyTracker-main/data.csv`?

Comment: Why are you passing the server something that looks like a path from the root of your file system? Exposing the whole of your file system over HTTP is a serious security risk.

Comment: @Quentin I get what you are saying. So how else could I get the contents of my csv file without it being from the root of my file system.

Comment: You configure your server using the Node.js code you still haven't shown us to expose a limited set of files.

Comment: @Quentin I added my node file. Not sure if that helps clear up anything.

Comment: You've got a lot of `app.get` and app.post` and so on. Which bit of that is supposed to handle the request for `/Users/danzam284/Desktop/DailyTracker-main/data.csv` ?

Comment: `app.get(__dirname + '/index.html',` — Well, that explains why the URL to the HTML document which `data.csv` gets appended to is so weird. Don't put your entire file system path in the *url*; you expose information about your file system and you end up with really really long and ugly URLs.

Comment: @Quentin The request for the csv occurs in the HTML file I included, not the node.js file. It is the document.ready function in the javascript <script>. Thank you though, I will try to work with the info you gave me.

Comment: Well, yes. The request *originates* from the client side code. Where do you think the request is made to to? What do you think makes the response? You're not writing a webserver in node js to handle requests that something else is already handling!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245472/discussion-between-daniel-zamloot-and-quentin).

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, this is my first time working with node.js so a lot of this stuff goes over my head. So what you are saying is that in order to access the csv file, I must formulate a response in the node file which sends the csv over?

Comment: Yes. The client asks for a URL. The server has to respond with what was asked for.